# pandas convert delta time column into one sole unit time

Tags: pandas, time, timedelta, units-of-measurement

I am working with a pandas dataframe where i have a deltatime column with values like:

{'deltatime': 0 days 09:06:30   , 0 days 00:30:34, 2 days 23:07:14  }

How can I convert those times into a single unit, like minutes, or hours but a single one in order to better visualize those times in a graph.
Some idea?

here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html

it does not clarify how to simple change units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `total_seconds()` method of a `timedelta` to get its duration in seconds:

```
seconds = [t.total_seconds() for t in df['deltatime']]
```

And then convert the units if desired:

```
#to hours, i.e. 3600 seconds
hours = [t.total_seconds()/3600 for t in df['deltatime']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df['deltatime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['deltatime']).dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
   deltatime
0    32790.0
1     1834.0
2   256034.0
```

You can also perform arithmetic operations on `timedelta`:

```
# convert to hours
pd.to_timedelta(df['deltatime']) / pd.to_timedelta('1H')
```

Output:

```
0     9.108333
1     0.509444
2    71.120556
Name: deltatime, dtype: float64
```